# Template for IEnumerable properties?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to template this class so that I can have a generic ListViewModel that can store `IEnumerable<Whatever>`. So instead of the following:

```
public class JamesListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<James> Jamess { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I would have:

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise for every list page that has pagination etc, i'm going to have to create a new view model. And more so, If I could get the latter to work. I could inherit and refine if needs be for a specific view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the class generic:

```
public class ListViewModel<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then, an instance can be created by supplying the type parameter like so:

```
var vm = new ListViewModel<string>();
```

Multiple type parameters can be separated by commas:

```
public class ListViewModel<T, U>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<U> OtherItems { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}

var vm = new ListViewModel<string, int>();
```

See [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the extra var vm part... very helpful

Comment: No problem. It might be worth noting that this isn't called a template in C#, but a *generic class*.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
public class ListViewModel<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

See the MSDN documentation for full details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx

Comment: ah so T in itself does that. Didn't know that! I'll give it a try